# Correctly pass struct to function in golang

Tags: go

I have a golang structure:

```
type Connection struct {
    Write chan []byte
    Quit chan bool
}
```

I'm creating it with:

```
newConnection := &Connection{make(chan []byte), make(chan bool)}
```

How to correctly create functional type with Connection parameter and function of this type?

I mean that i want to do something like this:

```
type Handler func(string, Connection)
```

and

```
handler(line, newConnection)
```

whene `handler` is:

```
func handler(input string, conn tcp.Connection) {}

cannot use newConnection (type *Connection) as type Connection in argument to handler
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try to create newConnection without the ampersand (&) operator. Does that help?

Answer (score 5):

the Problem is that the type of `Handler` is `Connection` and the value that you are passing is of type `*Connection`, i.e. Pointer-to-Connection.

Change the handler definition to be of type *Connection

Here is a working Example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Connection struct {
    Write chan []byte
    Quit  chan bool
}

type Handler func(string, *Connection)

func main() {
    var myHandler Handler

    myHandler = func(name string, conn *Connection) {
        fmt.Println("Connected!")
    }

    newConnection := &Connection{make(chan []byte), make(chan bool)}

    myHandler("input", newConnection)

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/8H2FocX5U9

Comment: This answer seems correct. I wonder, why it hasn't been accepted yet